Chain rule with functional derivative?
I posted the same question on math exchange but no answer yet, so I post it also here:
"I'd like to make the functional derivative of the functional $S[\phi(x)]$ with respect to the Fourier transform $\widetilde{\phi}(p)$ such that
$$\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}e^{ip\cdot x}\widetilde{\phi}(p)$$
Can I use the following chain rule
$$\frac{\delta S}{\delta\widetilde{\phi}(p)}[\phi]=∫{d^{d}x}\frac{\delta\phi(x)}{\delta{\widetilde{\phi}}(p)}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}[\phi]=∫ \frac{d^{d}x}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}e^{ip\cdot x}\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi(x)}[\phi]$$
or not?"

Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4925258/11127

I'd give you my answer considering a functional
$$S = \int_x L(\phi'(x), \phi(x), x) \, dx \ .$$
Since I didn't know the answer (and maybe still don't it, so watch out!), after the evaluation of the function $\phi(x)$ and its derivative with the transform,
$$\phi(x) = \int_k \hat{\phi}(k) e^{ikx} dk \quad, \quad \phi'(x) = i \int_k k \hat{\phi}(k) e^{ikx} dk$$
I'd start from the definition of the variation of a functional. I'd first evaluate the functional $S\left[\hat{\phi}(k) + \varepsilon\hat{w}(k) \right]$ and expand it at the first order in $\varepsilon$ (with $\hat{w}(k)$ the function usually indicated with $\delta \hat{\phi}(k)$ to remember that it's the variation of function $\hat{\phi}(k)$)
$$\begin{aligned}
S\left[ \hat{\phi}(k) + \varepsilon\hat{w}(k)\right] & = 
\int_x L\left(i \int_k k [ \hat{\phi}(k) +\varepsilon \hat{w}(k) ]  e^{ikx} dk, \int_k [ \hat{\phi}(k) + \varepsilon \hat{w}(k) ] e^{ikx} dk, x \right) dx \\
& = \int_x \left\{ L\left( i\int_k k \hat{\phi}(k)e^{ikx} , \int_k \hat{\phi}(k)e^{ikx}, x \right) +\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'} i \varepsilon  \int_k  k \, \hat{w}(k) e^{ikx} dk  +\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} \varepsilon  \int_k  \hat{w}(k) e^{ikx} dk \right\} dx +o (\varepsilon) \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
and subtract the non-variated functional to the the variation,
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{\hat{\phi}} S & = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left\{ S\left[ \hat{\phi}(k) + \varepsilon\hat{w}(k)\right] - S\left[ \hat{\phi}(k) \right]  \right\} = \\
 & = \int_x \left\{ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'} i \varepsilon  \int_k  \hat{w}(k) e^{ikx} dk  +\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} \varepsilon  \int_k  \hat{w}(k) e^{ikx} dk \right\} dx = \\
& = \int_k \underbrace{\int_x \left\{ i k \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'}  +\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} \right\}  e^{ikx} dx}_{=: \nabla_{\hat{\phi}(k) }S} \, \hat{w}(k) dk \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
with the last expression recast with the definition of the sensitivity w.r.t. the function $\hat{\phi}(k)$.

So the answer coincide, since this question raised when I was studying Polchinski eq. in LPA so I should have specified that S does not depend on the derivatives. Thank you btw

You're welcome. Glad to hear that it's been useful (and I'll imply I managed to provide a meaningful answer)
